# Ubuntu 18.04 /var/lib/snapd has 'other' write 40777

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-18.04

Tried to start Calculator in Ubuntu, but received the following message:

```
/var/lib/snapd has 'other' write 40777
```

Not sure what that means. I just want to start Calculator. Weird. Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Happened to me also. I changed the permissions of /var/lib/snapd from 777 to 755, so just do:

`sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/lib/snapd`

Comment: is there any other solution? Because if i give /var/lib/snapd 755 permission my docker won't start as docker need 777 permission.

Comment: This actually solves the problem of all the other snap apps that were not starting: slack, postman, spotify. Thanks lots man.

Answer (score 27):

In fact, to resolve the problem for all the applications related snap you must do:

```
sudo chmod 755 /
```

Comment: Don't do that. This command can destroy your OS for changing permissions of protected files. @Sven answer should be flagged as the correct one.

Comment: Agree w/ @JMoura - I did, in fact, hose my Chrome OS Linux container by running `sudo chmod 755 /` #LessonLearned lol.

any other thoughts, then?  I'm specifically seeing `/ has 'other' write 40777`, even after running the recommended answer.

Comment: @JoshuaPelton-Stroud. It shouldn't be possible to hose your system by just running chmod 755 /. It is just the root directory. If you do -R then it might be a problem, so just don't recurse.

Comment: I read @JMoura comment but went ahead with it anyways. Worked for me. Like Yasha has mentioned in the comment, this is not recursive.

Answer (score 5):

I was face "/has 'other' write 40777" problem when try to open vscode from terminal. That was fixed by "sudo chmod 755 /" command.